# ASP.NET Core AsyncActionFilter to log ActionArguments and Result

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, action-filter

I am looking to create a filter implementing `IAsyncActionFilter` that will retrieve data from the current request's context's `ActionParameters` and its `Result`. I'm using a custom attribute `MyLogAttribute` to direct the logging beheavior, e.g. to opt-in for logging and indicating fields with critical information.

```
public class AsyncMyLogFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var actionDescriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;

        if (actionDescriptor != null)
        {
            var attribute = actionDescriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttribute<MyLogAttribute>();

            if (attribute != null)
            {

                await next();

                // This is where the magic is supposed to happen:
                LoggerHelper.Log(context.ActionArguments, context.Result);
            }

            return;
        }

        await next();
    }
}
```

The way the filter provides a `next()` delegate led me to believe that past that point the action would be completed and the result object available for inspection as an `ObjectResult`. However, while the filter is able to grab the `ActionArguments` without problem, the `Result` property is unfortunately just null, which is not helpful at all.

The obvious alternative, the synchronous `IActionFilter`, lets me examine the `Result` object on the `OnActionExecuted` stage, but at this point the `ActionArguments` dictionary is not available.

So, is there any way to access both `ActionArguments` and `Result` within the same method scope?

-S

Comment: Are the arguments not available on `ActionExecutedContext.ActionDescriptor.Parameters`?

Comment: The Parameters collection includes the names and types of the parameters, but does not appear to hold their values.

Answer (score 2):

The result of `next()` will be the result context.

This code sample is from the [Filters documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#implementation)

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

    namespace FiltersSample.Filters
    {
        public class SampleAsyncActionFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
        {
            public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(
                ActionExecutingContext context,
                ActionExecutionDelegate next)
            {
                // do something before the action executes
                var resultContext = await next();
                // do something after the action executes; resultContext.Result will be set
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While the problem in its original form has not been resolved, I was able to create a workaround with an `IActionFilter`:

```
public class ActivityLogFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var actionDescriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;

        if (actionDescriptor != null)
        {
            var attribute = actionDescriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttribute<MyLogAttribute>();

            if (attribute != null)
            {
                context.HttpContext.Items["MyLogData"] = GetRelevantLogData(context.ActionArguments); // Apply some custom logic to select relevant log data
            }
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            var actionDescriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;

            if (actionDescriptor != null)
            {
                var attribute = actionDescriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttribute<MyLogAttribute>();

                if (attribute != null)
                {
                    var actionParametersData = (MyActionParametersLogData)context.HttpContext.Items["MyLogData"]

                    LoggerHelper.Log(actionParametersData, context.Result);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not exactly rocket science; it looks kinda flimsy (*"What if my HttpContext items go missing!?"*), but it seems to do the job.